# Node save filereader base64 svg upload with fs

Tags: node.js, svg, base64, fs, writefile

I try to save images uploaded from the client, my code works nicely with png's and jpg's but not with svg's. What is the best way?

Client side: `<input type="file>` => `fileReader.readAsDataURL` => `fileReader.result` => `xhr`

Server side:

```
saveUserImage(userid, file, base64, callback) {
  if(file.type.indexOf('image') != 0)
    return callback(false);

  var fs = require("fs");

  var regEx = new RegExp('^data:' + file.type + ';base64,');
  base64 = base64.replace(regEx, "");

  fs.mkdir('imgs', function() {
    fs.writeFile('imgs/' + userid + "_" + file.name, base64, 'base64', function(err) {
      if(err) return callback(false);
      return callback('imgs/' + userid + "_" + encodeURIComponent(file.name));
    });
  });
}
```

The saved svg's are wrong encoded I think:

```
u«ZŠf {û/ƒìf•¶¬{®Þ[™\œÚ[ÛHŒKŒˆ[˜ÛÙ[™ÏHš\ÛËN
NKLHÏ‚KKHÙ[™\˜]ÜŽˆYØ™H[\Ý˜]ÜˆNKŒŒÕ‘È^ÜYËR[ˆˆÕ‘È™\œÚ[ÛŽˆ
‹ŒZ[
HKO‚Ý™È™\œÚ[ÛHŒKŒHˆYH“^Y\—ÌHˆ[œÏHš‹ËÝÝÝËÌË›Ü™ËÌŒÜÝ™Èˆ[œÎž[šÏHš‹ËÝÝÝËÌË›Ü™ËÌNNNKÞ[šÈˆHŒˆOHŒ‚‚HšY]Ð›ÞHŒLËLŒHLËLŒHˆÝ[OH™[˜X›KX˜XÚÙÜ›Ý[™›™]ÈLËLŒHLËLŒNÈˆ[œÜXÙOHœ™\Ù\™H‚Ï‚‚OÏ‚‚BOÏ‚‚BBOÏ‚‚BBBOÏ‚‚BBBBO]Ý[OH™š[ˆÍÈˆH“LLLËŽLË‹Ž˜Í‹ŒÌLKÌ‹
ËŒÍKŒM‹‹ŒÍÎÌÎ‚BBBBBXËMKŒMKLŒN
LMKMËMKŽMLËL‹ŒÎ
‹MKŽÌ˜ËM‹ŒÌLËNÍMËŒÍKLŒML‹ŒÍÍËLÌÎ‚BBBBBPÎL‹ÎNÌ‹
ÍLËŒNN‹Ì
KLLËŽLË‹Žžˆ‹Ï‚‚BBBOÙÏ‚‚BBBOÏ‚‚BBBBO]Ý[OH™š[ˆÌÌÌÍŒÐNÈˆH“NKŽLNK
ÌËŒÌÍ˜ËM‹ŒÌLËNÍMËŒÍKLŒML‹ŒÍÍËLÌÎ‚BBBBBXÍKŒM‹LLŒN
MKM‹LMKŽMLË‹ŒÎ
KLMKŽÌˆ‹Ï‚‚BBBOÙÏ‚‚BBBOÏ‚‚BBBBO]Ý[OH™š[ˆÌÌÌÍŒÐNÈˆH“NLŒŒK
ÍŽÍØËLŒL‹LŒŒÎLŒKLŒÍNLŒ˜ËL
ÍLŒ
‹LŽLMËLŒŒÍLKŒNM‹LŒMÂ‚BBBBBXËM‹ŽLKNKLËMËŽ
KLŒKŽ
LKL‹MËLÌ‹ŒXÍKŒÌLËLLŒŽL‹MKÍÎKLM‹
‹ËŒÍÍ‹LM‹
˜ÌŒL‹ŒŒÎŒKŒÍNŒ‚‚BBBBBXÌ
ÍŒ
‹ŽLMËŒŒÍKŒNM‹ŒMØÍ‹ŽLKKLË
ËŽ
‹ŒKŽ
LK‹NÌ‹ŒPÌLL‹ŒÌË
Ž
LKŽ
```

svg support would be nice, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the mime type of svg is `image/svg+xml`! The plus is not escaped and the regex does not match. I used a simple function to escape and now it works perfekt

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might also try the `js-base64-file` module. Just save the raw svg to disk first and then convert it.

[github repo](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/js-base64-file)

```
const Base64File=require('js-base64-file');
const image=new Base64File;

const file='test.svg';

//path should alwas end in a /
const path=`${__dirname}/`;

//this will load and convert if needed
const data=image.loadSync(path,file);
console.log('you could send this image via ws or http to the browser now : \n',data);

image.save(data,path,`copy-b64-${file}`);
```

You can see an async example in the [test.js](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/js-base64-file/blob/master/test.js) file.